# Is it possible to register an inner class of a class as Broadcast receiver

Tags: android

In android, is it possible to register an inner class of a class as Broadcast receiver?

```
public class A extends AnotherClass {
   public class B extends BroadcasetReceiver {
   }
}
```

how can I register B of A to listen for an intent?

Comment: I tried doing this inside a class that extended `Service` and didn't have any luck.  It may have just been my implementation though.

Comment: Successfully did that in classes that extend Service and Activity. In that case IntentFilter is registered programatically and no need to register it in the Manifest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver as inner class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854807/broadcastreceiver-as-inner-class)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you can consider registering it with the [Context.registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver%28android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter%29). If you can make it static try to reference it this way from your AndroidManifest: `AnotherClass$BroadcasetReceiver`. Well... if it's static, why don't just create a top-level class?

Answer (score 3):

*Static* inner classes can be registered as broadcast receivers in the manifest.

The receiver is referred to by `.path.to.class.MyClass$MyInnerClass`

I don't think it is possible to reference a non-static inner class.