# How to implement the communication between a Service and an Activity in different processes?

Tags: android, android-service, android-activity, android-2.3-gingerbread

I read some similar questions (for example at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4300291/example-communication-between-activity-and-service-using-messaging)), but the problem I'm asking is a bit different. In fact, in my case the service is started manually by the `startService` method, then as a consequence it can not be started using the `bindService` method.

1. Suppose we have a package that contains the `MainService` service and `MainServiceActivity` activity. In the file *"AndroidManifest.xml"* this activity is declared with action `MAIN` and category `LAUNCHER`. This activity is used to configure the service via the `SharedPreferences` and start the service by invoking `startService` method. In other words, typically the user launches the `MainServiceActivity` and configures/starts the `MainService`.
2. Now consider another activity (Let's call it `SecondActivity`) that is part of another package. Depending on the configuration, the service starts this activity using the `startActivity` method, so this other activity is running on a separate process than the `MainService`. As soon as the activity is running, it should inform the service.
3. At this point, a communication request/reply begins between the `MainService` and the `SecondActivity`: the service sends a request and the activity sends a reply.

The communication via messaging might fit, but the `MainService` is started through `startService` method, so the `bindService` method can not be invoked by activities that want to bind to the service.

Then I had an idea that makes use of an additional service (Let's call it `UtilityService`), which is part of the same package of `MainService`: the `UtilityService` could be started using the `bindService` method. As a consequence:

- as soon as the `MainService` is running, it might perform the bind to the `UtilityService`;
- when the `MainService` launches an external activity (for example the above `SecondActivity`), this activity bind to the `UtilityService`.

In this way, both the `MainService` and the `SecondActivity` are connected to the `UtilityService`, where the latter acts as an intermediary for communication.

Are there alternatives to this idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In fact, in my case the service is started manually by the startService method, then as a consequence it can not be started using the bindService method.

You can both bind and start a service, if you wish. It's a bit unusual, but it can be done.

> Are there alternatives to this idea?

Binding has nothing in particular to do with services being able to communicate with activities. Using some sort of callback or listener object via binding is a possibility, but it is far from the only one.

You can:

- Have the service send a broadcast `Intent`, to be picked up by the activity
- Have the activity send a `PendingIntent` (e.g., via `createPendingResult()`) to the service in an `Intent` extra on the command sent via `startService()`, to be used by the service to send information back to the activity (or wherever the activity wants it to go, such as a broadcast)
- Have the activity pass a `Messenger` tied to its Handler to the service in an `Intent` extra on the command sent via `startService()`, to be used by the service to send information back to the activity

All of those work perfectly well between processes, as well as within a process.

Comment: _You can both bind and start a service, if you wish. It's a bit unusual, but it can be done._ Ok, it works! But, why is it unusual?

Comment: @enzom83: It is unusual because virtually nobody does it. Usually the command pattern (`startService()`) *or* the binding pattern (`bindService()`) is used.

Comment: Using a broadcast intent, can you decide who should receive it? I read about `setPackage` method in order to safely restrict the broadcast ([here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security), the fourth bullet point), but I'm working on Android 2.3. However I also read about the [`setComponent` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setComponent%28android.content.ComponentName%29), so I could set a known `BroadcastReceiver` as the destination of a broadcast intent. So would I get a kind of `sendUnicast` method?

Comment: @enzom83: "I'm working on Android 2.3" -- `setPackage()` was added in API Level 4. "So would I get a kind of sendUnicast method?" -- that only works for manifest-registered receivers, which will not work for your scenario. You are welcome to use `LocalBroadcastManager` from the Android Support package, as I illustrate here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Broadcast/Local

Comment: Ok, `setPackage` was added in API Level 4, but [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#Security) it says that _"starting with ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH, you can also safely restrict the broadcast to a single application with `Intent.setPackage`"_ However, about that kind of sendUnicast method, why does it will not work for my scenario? I could create a `BroadcastReceiver` (as an inner public class) in the service and another one in the activity and declare these receivers on the manifest of the two application packages... Or am I wrong?

Comment: @enzom83: " I could create a BroadcastReceiver (as an inner public class)" -- which will not work. You could register a `static public` inner class in the manifest. Android will then create a brand-new instance of that `BroadcastReceiver` when a broadcast is received, and that `BroadcastReceiver` instance will have no more ability to talk to your activity than does your current service. IOW, `setComponent()` and `registerReceiver()` cannot work together.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the reason. Thanks! I just saw that I can not declare an inner class defined in an activity as a receiver, so I should I declare it as static: however, declaring it static, it could not invoke non-static methods of my Activity.... But, just out of curiosity, why can not you register a simple inner class as a receiver?

Comment: @enzom83: Because Android needs to create an instance of a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`, and only an instance of the outer class can create an instance of a non-static inner class.

Comment: And, what about [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4854830/364056)? Could it work?

Comment: @enzom83: Not with `setComponent()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/aidl.html).

You can find an easy to use guide [here](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/48.html)

Comment: AIDL is an option. It is most certainly not the only option.

Comment: @rui.araujo: I read something about AIDL and I understood that its goal is the same as the messaging, but AIDL should be is more simple compared to the messaging. I looked at the guide you have linked and tomorrow I will read it in more detail.

Comment: @CommonsWare You're right. Using "have to" is silly. Still I like AIDL the most. It just feels clean. ;)

Comment: Well, I read the guide you have linked and I also tried an example available [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AdvServices) (RemoteClient and RemoteService). Now I'm trying to reverse the direction of communication, that is, from the remote service to the client.

Comment: I am interested in this solution u mention in the last comment @enzom83 . Did u make any progress with it? 10q

Comment: @Ewoks: To establish a bidirectional communication, I defined two AIDL interfaces, `IService` and `IServiceCallback`: the application sends data to the service using the `IService` interface, and the service sends data to the application using the `IServiceCallback` interface. [This page](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) explains how to implement an AIDL interface.