# How can i get recevier instance(which is registered in AndroidManifest.xml) in activity

Tags: android

I've register a receiver in AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<receiver android:name="com.sunrise.taximate.message.MessageRecevier"> 
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="xxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx" /> 
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and now I want to get the receiver's instance in one of my activities(Like MainActivity),but I don't know how to. anyone can help me?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want!

Comment: why do you want to do that? if you want to communicate with this receiver then you can generate an Broadcast and it would be receive by the receiver registered in the manifest..

Answer (score 1):

```
private BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // Your code here to do what ever you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Receivers are meant to act on events generated by the system and sometimes the users. There are special cases where you might want to get an instance of those yourself but this is uncommon. The whole point of having receivers is to react to system events and take some action. Unless you know what you are doing, I would recommend against creating receiver instances yourself in an activity.

If you really want to, you can do it like this

```
private BroadcastReceiver myReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Also see this thread for related info:
[BroadcastReceiver as inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854807/broadcastreceiver-as-inner-class)

Comment: you mean I should create two broadcastReceiver(receiverA,receiverB)?   receiverA is registered in manifest.xml，and receiverB is registered in activity dynamic， When receiverA receive a message, it send a new broadcast to notify receiverB？

Comment: No. There is just one receiver (Receiver A) registered in the manifest .xml. When it receives a message, it will just do whatever it needs to with it and run whatever code you need to run. There is no need to have another receiver in your activity at all